# How to extend an ES6 class in a TypeScript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a JavaScript class written in ES6:

```
// MyClass.js
export default class MyClass {
  myfunction() {
    console.log('myfunction called');
  }
}
```

I'd like to extend this class with a TypeScript class:

```
// MyTSClass.ts
import MyClass from './MyClass';

class MyTSClass extends MyClass {
  public initialize() {
    this.myfunction();
  }
}
```

This produces a TypeScript compiler error:

> TS2339: Property 'myfunction' does not exist on type 'MyTSClass'

I have `esModuleInterop` set to `true` in my tsconfig.

I attempted to make a declaration file, thinking this might help:

```
// MyClass.d.ts
export = MyClass;

declare class MyClass {
  myfunction: void;
}
```

This makes the compiler happy, but in the generated code in the browser I see something unexpected, and the console log does not print:

```
class MyTSClass extends WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["MyClass"]...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The compiler being happy and the generated code not functioning aren't necessarily related. You've done the right thing to get it to compile, now you need to figure out why your code isn't working. Start by reading the error you get, or if there is none, by figuring out exactly what it's doing, and what it needs to do instead.

Comment: In short, you've solved one problem, now you have another, and there's not nearly enough information here currently to qualify as a [mcve] for reproducing the problem, because all you've said about it is "the functionality doesn't work".

Comment: Thanks, I updated the example to show a `console.log` in the original function that is not printed. I haven't included webpack config, tsconfig, etc. since I'm not sure which parts are relevant. I was hoping I was doing something wrong that was easily identifiable to one with experience, but can take the time to spin up a more complete example soon.

Comment: You're not instantiating the class and using it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the info you've provided, but I would start at whatever is calling `initialize`. I'm assuming you didn't mean to use `constructor` instead? In Chrome, you can use the `debugger;` statement to launch the debugger at a specific point in your code, which I think is easier than setting breakpoints. From there, you can step through the code and see what's going on. You could also console.log the instance of your class to inspect its prototype chain to make sure the `myfunction` method is there.

Comment: "Start debugging by looking around X" is not an answer. Best to wait for OP to clarify the question enough to make the question fully answerable.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation for the downvote, but I would argue debugging is how the OP will find the answer. Ultimately, if he learns to debug, he'll be better equipped to find answers on his own.

Comment: Thanks, I'm embarrassed to admit the problem was in the class that called `initialize`. I'm accepting the answer since it was helpful.